# Template validation failed when using SAM syntax instead of CloudFormation syntax for step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions, aws-sam, infrastructure-as-code

I have the following step function in my AWS SAM template, it was defined using the syntax in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-statemachine.html#sam-statemachine-definitionsubstitutions). I'm using [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) to get some [pseudoparameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html) but something is going wrong with them.

```
SfdcOrderEventsStepFunction:
Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
Properties:
  DefinitionSubstitutions:
    Region: !Ref "AWS::Region"
    AccountId: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
    EventBusPublishTarget: "order-events"
  DefinitionUri: sfn-definition.asl.yml
  Events:
    EventBridgeEvent:
      Type: EventBridgeRule
      Properties:
        EventBusName: sfdc-events
        Pattern:
          # TODO: Update pattern when the salesforce service is ready
          source:
            - prefix: salesforce.com
          detail-type:
            - Order
          detail:
            Payload__c:
              attributes:
                type:
                  - order
        InputPath: $.detail
  Name: sfdc-order-events
  Role: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/stepfunction_execution_role'
  Tracing:
    Enabled: true
```

when I try to deploy it shows me the following error:

> Resource template validation failed for resource
> SfdcOrderEventsStepFunction as the template has invalid properties.
> Please refer to the resource documentation to fix the template.
> Properties validation failed for resource SfdcOrderEventsStepFunction
> with message:
> #/De finitionSubstitutions/ AccountId: 2 subschemas matched instead of one
> #/DefinitionSubstitutions/AccountId: expected type: Boolean, found: String

At the end it deploys without problems. The step function and all of its components run as expected and without errors, but I wanted to know if there if something I can do to fix the template.

Comment: Could it be that in your `sfn-definition.asl.yml` you use the `AccountId` as a boolean value ?

Comment: not really, I used them like this: 
"Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:${Region}:${AccountId}:function:sfdc-order-notifications-lock-step" 
But I've realized that the failed validation it's because of the SAM syntax (Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine) instead of CloudFormation syntax :(